# GUI Preview Sizes Issue When Developing WinForm App in Surface Pro 3

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I had been developing WinForm apps in a long time. I just recently bought a Surface Pro 3 to serve as my new development PC. Unfortunately I noticed an issue with the GUI editor. The some of the sizes of the controls don't match with what appears in the GUI editor and with what appears in the actual running application. For example, the sizes of my panels don't follow what it looks like in the GUI editor when I run the app. They usually increase in dimension. I am not really sure if it is a VS issue or maybe it has something to do specifically with using Surface Pro 3?

To demonstrate what I mean consider the following screenshots. Notice the difference in the size of the Menu Bar in the GUI Editor and in the actual application.

[image: GUI EDITOR VIEW]

[image: RUNNING APP VIEW]

Comment: This typically happens on high DPI screens.  Check your DPI settings.  Anything other than "Normal 100%" causes glitches like this in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I posted this question and I kinda forgot about it. I thought I should share my recent findings for those who will find themselves in this same predicament.

I learned that the discrepancy between the GUI editor and the actual running app was because of the super high DPI scaling of my Surface Pro 3. Visual Studio was automatically running at 216 DPI (225% display scaling) compared to the usual 96 DPI (100% display scaling) of common computers. My workaround back then was to simply adjust my controls accordingly thru trial and error and to anchor most of them between the GUI editor and the running app. Eventually, it became less of an issue since I moved on to a normal desktop with a normal screen for my regular software development. Moving forward, I recently stumbled upon a [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms) regarding Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms. It explains the issues with multiple DPI scaling for Windows Forms. It also includes this bit about the DPI scaling issue of Visual Studio:

> With the extreme differences in display DPIs, especially in modern 2-in-1 devices, this can still happen with the most current versions of the .NET Framework and Visual Studio. To address this in a team using different DPI displays, make sure Visual Studio always starts in a non-DPI-aware mode, so the Windows Forms designer always bases the layout calculation on 96 DPI.

The solution they suggested is to add or import a registry value that disables Visual Studio's High DPI awareness:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\devenv.exe]
"dpiAwareness"=dword:00000000
```

I tried it and it definitely works. I hope it helps you too. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent your app from changing size, you can make it independent of DPI settings. Your app will be pixel perfect but on high resolution screens may be too small.

All you have to do is to change `AutoScaleMode` property of the main form and set it as `None`.

[image]

Comment: What affect does that have on resizing/docking/anchoring?

Comment: I don't think this works. There is still that noticeable change in size between the GUI editor and the running app.

GUI
http://i.imgur.com/fYCuPnL.png

RUNNING
http://i.imgur.com/8xWvDje.png

Comment: It certainly works in some scenarios. Check any code that deals with auto sizing, parent windows, etc. that may coincide with this fix.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I was experiencing the same issue... I found a workaround which you may find useful...

After trying a few things it became obvious to me that windows 10 was attempting some "intelligent" resizing of forms under Windows 10 on the surface pro (I am using a surface pro 4)... I am not sure if it is a win10, high-res or surface pro issue.... whatever it is it was messing up my control sizing, placement, anchors and resolution.

I found that if I made a note of the intended size of my form in the designer and then manually set this in code at the end of my Form_Load event, it would override this unintended behaviour and I ended up with my originally intended form size and control placement, I also needed to re-center the form in the parent/screen to get the desired result (of course only if that is the intended start-up position for your form)

The code that worked for me (at the end of the Form_Load event) is...

```
this.height = 800;
this.width = 600;
this.CenterToScreen();
```

I hope this helps somebody, I was pulling my hair out for a while!